# I don't understand this tree structure

Tags: tree

```
type Item = string
type tree = LEAF of Item
          | NODE of tree list
```

I'm having trouble understanding this. For example:

```
Node [Node [Item "a", Item "h", Item "b"], Item "k", Node [Item "c", Item "h", Item "d"]]
```

Could you draw a graph of this? It would be a great help.

It's not that I don't know about trees.

Answer (score 0):

The tree that is described by that syntax, corresponds to this visualisation:

```
      Node
     /  |  \
  Node  k  Node
  / | \    / | \
 a  h  b  c  h  d
```

The structure is such that only leaves (i.e. `Item`) have data (of type string). Internal nodes (`Node`) do not have data.